# 'sudo apt-get upgrade' yields 'E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)' [ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

Trying to `sudo apt-get upgrade` yields

```
dpkg: error processing package python3-problem-report (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-problem-report
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

First day in office after holidays and I've done nothing but booting my machine.
Any suggestions?

*Edits:*

Yeah, I tried to reinstall the specific python3-problem-report package, but I encountered the same error

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-problem-report
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems that there is something fundamentally broken. I restarted my machine and after the restart I tried `sudo apt-get autoremove`

```
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-problem-report
 python3-apport
 apport
 apport-gtk
 xdiagnose
 ubuntu-desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the package as the error message suggested?

Comment: See http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/